# Can't compile MailJet sample program (c#)

Tags: c#, mailjet

I am trying to use MailJet to send a test email.

I have created a new project and use sample code provided in this page
https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/getting-started/
I have added nuget Mailjet.api (3.0.0)

Result : The sample code does not compile.
CS0117  'MailjetClient' does not contain a definition for 'Version'
Version property is used in this code :

```
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(API_KEY, SecretKey)
     {
         Version = ApiVersion.V3_1,
     };
```

Looks like I don't use the right nuget because class MailjetClient does not have the Version Property.

Expected : The sample code compiles.

Question : What do I do wrong?

Note : If I comment the line which sets Version, program compiles and run, but does not work. The error is as follow, even if I provide FromEmail (which is present in the sample code)
StatusCode: 400
ErrorInfo: At least FromEmail or Sender must be provided

Comment: The code clearly shows that `MailClient` indeed does not have `Version` property. I'd recommend to delete it and investigate the problem that shows _then_.

Comment: Also mind https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/send-api-V3/#send-api-v3-to-v3.1 ... the 3.0.0, according to nuget, is the most recent, so that should be the correct one to use.